# How to get html that I see in inspect element?

Tags: python, web-scraping

I'm programming a web-scraper app with python. The website I want to scrape data use JS.
How can I get the source that I see in inspect element?

Answer (score 1):

With javascript pycurl will not work, you need [Selenium](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/selenium) to get the stuff you need.

```
import selenium
driver = selenium.webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("your_url")
```

Make sure you have Firefox (or another browser selenium supports) installed.

Comment: I want the page html after js do it's function!

Comment: Yeah that's what this will get you, either with driver.page_source after a waiting period [(check here)](http://docs.seleniumhq.org/docs/04_webdriver_advanced.jsp). Or, if the website is really unwilling, by using save_screenshot and OCR (that you probably have to write yourself).