# How to extract source from website as we see in inspect element

Tags: web-scraping, jsoup, htmlunit

I would like to extract the complete html source of website as we get it on chrome inspect element.

I am trying to the scrap the comments of disqus from http://bossip.com/1190557/cops-kill-people-mississippi-cop-under-investigation-for-strangling-unarmed-black-man-jonathan-sanders-to-death-43081/

Initially I tried with java and Jsoup but I am unable to extract the complete html source.

Then as suggested in [How to get html that I see in inspect element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23971096/how-to-get-html-that-i-see-in-inspect-element) I tried using HTML Unit but unfortunately HTML unit also did not extract as i expected.

Is there any solution around for this problem?

Comment: "Save Page As" in your browser?

Comment: is there any Java library to do that?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid Even on manual save I don't find the expected contents, I did it on google Chrome

Answer (score -1):

In Chrome,

1. in normal browser document: right-click on element, select "Inspect Element" from pop-up menu. You will go to the "developer tools" window.
2. in developer tools window: right-click on the HTML element and select "Edit as HTML" from pop-up menu.
3. select all HTML text in the editor (press CTRL-A) and copy to clipboard (press CTRL-C)

Comment: not sure why this is downvoted. It works as described.

Comment: since @Arun Kishore asked how to get the html of one very specific page your solution works great, but the down vote was likely due to this being such a manual task. It can't be automated.